How to ask whether a store has trousers of a particular size?
For example, how to ask, "Do you have trousers of size 52-4?"

Есть ли у вас брюки размера 52-4?

брюки or штаны, the latter being more colloquial.

Брюки means trousers, штаны means pants. I think брюки is a subset of штаны. It's not about colloquial or not, it's just different kind of pants.

But pants means trousers (in US English). What makes you think there is a difference in the meaning of those English words? Your comment is not comprehensible.

Well, брюки is normally reserved for more formal trousers that have a crease, like those you wear as part of a suite. You would wear them to work in the office. Штаны can be anything including sport pants. This difference is somewhat blurred but I wouldn't refer to sport pants as брюки. Also note that neither of the words refers to underwear. In British English, the word pants also means underwear, what in Russian is called кальсоны or подштанники. You wear those under your trousers to keep you warm.

The word "штаны" indeed has a slightly different emotional flavor. It is not colloquial, but it is a simpler word that refers to all pants including cheap ones. If you want to emphasize that you need a more formal (perhaps also more expensive-looking) piece of clothing, use "брюки". But if you want to say that someone has no pants on, you would say, "Он без штанов", because you do not care what kind of pants exactly he forgot to put on. When it comes to jeans, they are called "джинсы", they are also a kind of pants.

Thank you. I see now. The word I know for underwear is трусы, but may that is only for boxers or a particular sort of underwear.

кальсоны is a word I've come across before, but seems like "long johns" to me.

It's a different type of underwear with long legs, just like pants but you wear it under your normal pants. Just do google image search and you'll understand what I mean.

Yes, they are "Long Johns", but England is not cold enough to need to wear them.
